# Spell-checking application in C++

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, tree, homework

This is my current coursework for university where I am to write a spell checking application and compile using C++11.

I have a dictionary file that is read into the program automatically and stored into a binary search tree in order. The user provides a text file that they would like to check which is split into tokens and stored in a string vector.

The program then loops through the string vector and checks if that word exists in the BST. If the word is not in the BST, it will print the word to the console as incorrectly spelled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include "bst.h"

using namespace std;

string read_file(string &filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename);
    // If there is a file
    if (file)
    {
        string data;
        // Find total number of bytes of file
        file.seekg(0, file.end);
        data.resize(file.tellg());
        file.seekg(0, file.beg);
        // Read text into data string
        file.read(&data[0], data.size());
        // Close the file
        file.close();
        // Return the string
        return data;
    }
    else return string("");
}

void split_words(vector<string> &words, string &data)
{
    char *token, *delim = " .,?!:;/\"\'\n\t";
    // Set token to first word
    token = strtok(&data[0], delim);
    // Split rest of words
    while (token != nullptr)
    {
        // Convert each word from dictionary to lower case
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(token); ++i)
        {
            char word = tolower(token[i]);
            token[i] = word;
        }
        // Push word to end of vector
        words.push_back(token);
        // Get the next word
        token = strtok(nullptr, delim);
    }
    // Free the memory
    token = nullptr;
    delim = nullptr;
    delete token;
    delete delim;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string file_to_check, file_data, word_dictionary = "dictionary.txt";
    int spell_count = 0;

    BinarySearchTree *tree = new BinarySearchTree();
    vector<string> words;

    // Loop through arguments
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        // Set file name if provided as argument
        if (string(argv[i]) == "-i" && argv[i+1] != nullptr)
            file_to_check = argv[i+1];
    }

    // If there was no file name as argument, prompt user
    if (file_to_check.empty())
    {
        cout << "File name: ";
        getline(cin, file_to_check);
        cout << endl;
    }

    // If file name is not empty, run spell checking methods
    if (!file_to_check.empty())
    {
        // Read words from dictionary.txt into file_data string
        file_data = read_file(word_dictionary);
        // Split the words and store into vector
        split_words(words, file_data);
        // Insert words into Binary Search Tree
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
            stringstream(words[i]) >> *tree;

        // Store the data read from specified file
        file_data = read_file(file_to_check);
        // Split sentences and store each word in words vector
        split_words(words, file_data);
        cout << endl;

        // Loop through words vector and check if it exists in dictionary
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
        {
            // Print out non-occurring words
            if (!tree->exists(words[i]))
            {
                spell_count++;
                cout << words[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;

        // Print the total number of spelling mistakes
        cout << spell_count << " spelling mistakes" << endl;
    } 
    else
    {
        // If still no file specified, print message and exit
        cout << "No file specified!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Free the memory
    delete tree;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the "bst.h" header so people can compile this? Maybe also provide an input sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `using namespace std;` [Never do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [Prefer using `\n` over `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n) as the latter flushes the buffer which is rarely needed and can be detrimental to performance.
- `const` your arguments whenever possible. [More about const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)
- `*` and `&` are considered to be part of the type in C++ so prefer writing `int& foo` instead of `int &foo`. Likewise for `*`.
- Never omit optional braces as doing so will lead to bugs eventually.
- [Reaching the end of main will automatically return 0](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.3.html) so you can remove the trailing `return 0`
- Don't initialize more than one variable per line.
- I like that you use the prefix operator. Your naming is pretty good too so why are you doing this?

  ```
  // Close the file
  file.close();
  ```

  or this

  ```
  // Loop through arguments
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
  ```

  Your comments are completely superfluous and can all be removed.
- What is this?

  ```
  // Free the memory
  token = nullptr;
  delim = nullptr;
  delete token;
  delete delim;
  ```

`delete` is only used after a matching `new`. It feels like you misunderstood something in regard to memory managment. Read up on this again.
[new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)
[delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)
[memory managment](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt)

- `BinarySearchTree *tree = new BinarySearchTree();`

I don't know how this is implemented but a line like that looks like something from Java. Do you really *need* to put this on the heap?

- Personally I think the word splitting could be done rather elegantly in regex. However many people are quite opposed to using regex. I've also read that in the past regex performance in C++ was rather poor but it might be worth measuring to see if it's within acceptable limits for your use-case.

Regex example:

```
std::regex rx{R"(([^ .,?!:;/\"\'\n\t]+))"};
auto data_begin = std::sregex_iterator(data.begin(), data.end(), rx);
auto data_end = std::sregex_iterator();
for (std::sregex_iterator it = data_begin; it != data_end; ++it) {
    // do something with words here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback! We were given the binary search tree as a class hence the use of new. I will make changes based on your suggestions :)

Comment: @TobyCook: you don't need to use `new` just because it's a class. You can write `BinarySearchTree tree;`, and then you don't need the `delete` at the end either. Less typing, fewer bugs! :)

Answer (score 4):

I have two more comments to add to Yuri's answer:

1. Prefer to always initialize variables the moment you declare them:

   ```
   char *token, *delim = " .,?!:;/\"\'\n\t";
   token = strtok(&data[0], delim);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   char const* delim = " .,?!:;/\"\'\n\t";
   char* token = strtok(&data[0], delim);
   ```
2. And don't declare variables until you need them. In C you had to declare all variables at the beginning of a function (I think the newest standard doesn't require this any more?) but in C++ you don't. There are advantages to declaring the variables where you need them: you can initialize them right away to a meaningful value, and you reduce their scope, reducing the probability of mistakes.

   For example `spell_count` can be declared just before the loop that uses it, inside the `if` statement. Likewise for all the strings except the file name.

Oh, one more thing. Three comments. Three comments to add to Yuri's answer:

3. I'd suggest using `constexpr` for constants, or at least `const`:

   ```
   constexpr char const* word_dictionary = "dictionary.txt";
   ```

   Note also the `const` I added to the `delim` variable under point 1. I think you should get at least a compiler warning if you don't, because you're pointing at unmutable data.

   I prefer constants to be declared at the top of the file, where they're easy to spot. At least the constants like `word_dictionary` that are configurable in the source code and you might want to adjust at some point.

Comment: Thanks Cris, I've taken on board your first two points. However, I noticed you changed my declaration of `word_dictionary` from `std::string` to `char const*`. Are there any advantages of using the latter?

Comment: @TobyCook: None that I know of. I wasn't sure if `std::string` could be `constexpr`. `char*` implicitly converts to `std::string`, and you only use it as input to a function, so there's really no difference in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Everything important has been already said. Just a few minor notes:

1. you should reduce nesting in `read_file` function.

   Instead of:

   ```
   if (file)
   {
       // Load the file
       return data;
   }
   else return string("");
   ```

   You can do:

   ```
   if (!file)
   {
       return string("");
   }

   // Load the file
   return data;
   ```

   This makes code much more readable.
2. If the file loading fails, you just simply return empty string and then try to parse it. This silent fail is very dangerous, you should definitely consider throwing an exception in case the file open fails:

   ```
   if (!file)
   {
       throw std::runtime_error("Dictionary failed to load");
   }
   ```

   This change obviously requires `try` - `catch` block within function `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Errors should be printed to the standard error stream, and cause the program to terminate with a failure (non-zero) status:

```
    std::cerr << "No file specified!\n";
    return 1;
```